# Shift in the right of last item of the menu

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

Delphi Xe2U4. Main menu items: File, Option, Help (name: HelpMenuItem). 2 buttons. Use StyleManager Xe2 (in project option enabled xe2 themes, and default set 'Metro Blue').

```
Procedure TForm1.RightMenu; // Shift in the right of last item of the menu
var mii: TMenuItemInfo;MainMenu: hMenu; Buffer: array[0..79] of Char;
begin
  MainMenu := Self.Menu.Handle;
  mii.cbSize := SizeOf(mii) ;
  mii.fMask := MIIM_TYPE;
  mii.dwTypeData := Buffer;
  mii.cch := SizeOf(Buffer) ;
  GetMenuItemInfo(MainMenu, HelpMenuItem.Command, false, mii) ;
  mii.fType := mii.fType or MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY;
  SetMenuItemInfo(MainMenu, HelpMenuItem.Command, false, mii) ;
end;

procedure TForm1.Metro1Click(Sender: TObject); // Not Work
begin
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Metro Blue'); // or any other
RightMenu;
end;

procedure TForm1.Windows1Click(Sender: TObject); // Work
begin
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Windows'); // standart theme
RightMenu;
end;
```

Why does not work at use theme?
Whether or there is a normal way to shift last point of the menu in the right, whether is not dependent schemes are applied or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunally the vcl style hook of the [`TMainMenu`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMainMenu) doesn't implement the code to draw a particular menu item aligned to the right. Also this vcl style hook (TMainMenuBarStyleHook) is embedded in the TFormStyleHook (the vcl style hook for the forms) as a strict private member, so there is not much room for modifications here. Fix this issue will require which you rewrite the a new vcl style hook for the TForms and the TMainMenus. So If you want  do this you must copy the TFormStyleHook class from the Vcl.Forms unit to a new unit and then fix the implementation of the `TFormStyleHook.TMainMenuBarStyleHook.DrawItem` and the `TFormStyleHook.TMainMenuBarStyleHook.Paint` methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
Procedure TForm1.RightMenu; // Shift in the right of last item of the menu
var mii: TMenuItemInfo;MainMenu: hMenu; Buffer: array[0..79] of Char;
begin
  MainMenu := Self.Menu.Handle;
  mii.cbSize := SizeOf(mii) ;
  mii.fMask := MIIM_TYPE;
  mii.dwTypeData := Buffer;
  mii.cch := SizeOf(Buffer) ;
  GetMenuItemInfo(MainMenu, HelpMenuItem.Command, false, mii) ;
  mii.fType := mii.fType or MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY;
  if SetMenuItemInfo(MainMenu, HelpMenuItem.Command, false, mii) then DrawMenuBar(self.Menu.WindowHandle);

end;
```

Comment: Do you really need the `Buffer` and `dwTypeData` stuff? Isn't `mii.fMask := MIIM_FTYPE` enough?