# Firemonkey and right justify a main menu item

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How can the last menu item in Firemonkey be moved to the right edge of the form ? I found solutions only for VCL.

Comment: Please provide more information in your question. Which control are you using as "menu", what have you tried so far, is it platform-specific, etc?

Comment: I use  TMainMenu component and I tried  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594084/shift-in-the-right-of-last-item-of-the-menu

Answer (score 0):

TMainMenu and TMenuItem have very limited options regarding design, and setting custom alignment to both is currently not available in Delphi Alexandria (from what I've seen, at least). TMenuItem has a public (not published) property 'Align', but it is ignored when TMainMenu is drawn (similar behavior as in TGridLayout).

Maybe you'd go better off creating your own main menu with layouts, where you can properly calculate the width and height of menu buttons depending on the screen size.